# Numerical problem

Tags: numerical-methods

The value of 1001 to the power 3?. Any trick for quick answer?

Comment: The easiest method is a calculator, and the answer is 1003003001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(1001)^3=(1000+1)^3$$

Now use $(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3$

Also $(1000)^n=(10^3)^n=10^{3n}$

For integer $r\ge0,10^r$ has $r$ zeros following the initial $1$

Answer (score 0):

What about  $$(1000+1)^3=1000000000+3000000+3000+1?$$